# How can i solve these?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I have done them but I am unsure if I did them right.How could i solve this?

$\frac{2x^2-x-19}{x^2+3x+2}>1$

$-1<\frac{2x+3}{x-1}<1$

Comment: Could you post up your working? This site looks more kindly on verifying working than simply solving questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for b) we get two cases
I) $$x^2+3x+2>0$$ this is fulfilled for $$x<-2$$ or $$x>-1$$ multiplying by $$x^2+3x+2>0$$ gives 
$$x<-3$$ or $$x>7$$ this is our solution set for the case a)
II) $$x^2-4x-21<0$$ is fulfilled for $$-2<x<-1$$ and multiplying by $$x^2+3x+2<0$$ gives $$x^2-x-19<0$$ this is fulfilled for $$-3<x<7$$ and we get the solutionset $$-2<x<-1$$
c) for the inequality $$-1<\frac{2x+3}{x-1}<1$$ we get $$x<-2$$ (this can you prove by yourself!)

Answer (score 2):

Hint

$$f(x)/g(x)>1\Leftrightarrow \frac{f(x)-g(x)}{g(x)}>0\Leftrightarrow (f(x)-g(x))g(x)>0$$

Comment: thank you. i can't vote you i need 15 points.

Comment: @User21 I'm glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

For two see See [Solve this inequality equation with 3 sides?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1406470/solve-this-inequality-equation-with-3-sides)

For one,

$$\dfrac{2x^2-x-19}{x^2+3x+2}<1\iff\dfrac{2x^2-x-19}{x^2+3x+2}-1<0$$

$$\iff\dfrac{x^2-4x-21}{x^2+3x+2}<0$$

$$\iff\dfrac{(x-7)(x+3)}{(x+2)(x+1)}<0$$

$$\iff0>(x-7)(x+3)(x+2)(x+1)=(x-7)\{x-(-1)\}\{x-(-2)\}\{x-(-3)\}$$

So, we need odd number of negative multiplicands

$-1<x<7\implies $ only $x-7<0$

and $-3<x<-2\implies$ only $x+3>0$

Comment: @MarioG, Thanks for you observation. Please find the updated answer